# Python: Sort nested list

Tags: python, sorting

I have a nested list like following structure:

```
nested_list = [ ['text1', index1], ['text2', index2], ['text3', index3], [], ..., ['text12', index54] ].
```

The item 'index' is an integer and does not correspond to the index of the list. As you can, see I also have some empty lists.

I want to sort this nested list according to the item 'index'. My current approach fails:

```
sorted_list = sorted(nested_list, key = lambda x: x[1])
```

I think its because of those empty lists, as I receive following error:

```
IndexError 
list index out of range
```

So I tried the following:

```
sorted_list = sorted(nested_list, key = lambda x: x[1] if len(x) > 0)
sorted_list = sorted(nested_list, key = lambda x: x[1] and len(x) > 0)
```

But all those are syntax errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want those empty lists to be at the end or the beginning?

Comment: You probably want `key=lambda x: x[1] if len(x) > 0 else 0`. Alternatively, `sorted(filter(bool, nested_list), key=lambda x: x[1])` should ignore any empty fields and not include them in the output.

Comment: `x[1] if len(x) > 0` is a syntax error because you don't have an `else` case.

Comment: `key=lambda x: x[1] if len(x) > 0 else 0` still gives me a type error: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'

Comment: According to that error, `x[1]` is itself a list, which is not the case in your posted data structure.  Does your actual data structure have sub-sub-lists?

Answer (score 0):

A [conditional expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) always needs an `else` part. How else can the expression's value be determined in case the condition does not hold:

```
sorted_list = sorted(nested_list, key = lambda x: x[1] if x else 0)
```

Whether `0` is a useful default value depends on your data. If you have negative as well as positive `index` values, the empty lists will be sorted somewhere in the middle.

Comment: `key=lambda x:x and x[1]` could be better

Comment: @python_learner That doesn't work, since it will evaluate to `[]` if x is `[]` and the sort will fail.  It would have to be `lambda x: len(x) and x[1]` which will work.